# How can I solve http 405 error on IIS server

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, deployment, web-hosting

I've deployed next.js web site to iis server.
When I run it on local computer it shows correct response but if I run it on IIS server then it doesn't get image and the error is 405 error.
Please help me if you have experience with 405 error on IIS server.

I've tried to deploy next.js web site on IIS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive an error message similar to the following example:

> Server Error in Application "application name"
> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method not allowed
> HRESULT: 0x80070001
> Description of HRESULT
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method(HTTP verb) is being used.

This problem may occur for several reasons:

1. the client makes a Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) request by using an HTTP method that doesn't comply with the HTTP specifications.
2. The client makes an HTTP request by sending the POST method to a page that is configured to be handled by the StaticFile handler. For example, a client sends the POST method to a static HTML page. However, pages that are configured for the StaticFile handler don't support the POST method.
3. WebDAV Publishing interferes with HTTP PUT.

The corresponding solutions are as follows:

1. In the ApplicationHost.config file, find the  tag. Make sure all handlers use valid HTTP methods.
2. Send the POST request to a page that's configured to be handled by a handler other than the StaticFile handler. For example, the ASPClassic handler. Or, change the request that is being handled by the StaticFile handler so that it's a GET request instead of a POST request.
3. Remove WebDAV modules and handlers from the Web.config file. Also remove the WebDAV Publishing feature from your computer if it's not being used.

For more details, please refer to this official Microsoft document:
[HTTP Error 405.0 when you visit a website that is hosted on a server that is running IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website). If you get a different error than this, please provide more details about your problem.